# CosmosDbPartitionedStorage read() function not working on serverless cosmos DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-cosmosdb, azure-bot-service

```
const { CosmosDbPartitionedStorage } = require('botbuilder-azure');

// Create access to CosmosDb Storage - this replaces local Memory Storage.
var storage = new CosmosDbPartitionedStorage({
    cosmosDbEndpoint: dbConfig.DB_SERVICE_ENDPOINT, 
    authKey: dbConfig.AUTH_KEY, 
    databaseId: dbConfig.DATABASE_ID,
    containerId: dbConfig.CONTAINER,
    compatibilityMode: false
})

let storeItems = await storage.read(['id']);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzPwU.png)

```
console.log(storeItems)
```

output is: {}
*getting only blank object not the desired data*

**Note: same code is working when we use **Provisioned throughput Cosmos DB**

Comment: can you paste the image?

Comment: Not sure what `CosmosDbPartitionedStorage` is but on Serverless mode, any calls to obtain the RU provisioned on a container fail with an HTTP 400, if this `CosmosDbPartitionedStorage` internally tries to obtain the provisioned RU, that could explain the problem.

Comment: I am able to get the data. Are you sure you're passing the correct id (`User...` in your screenshot) of the document here `await storage.read(['id']);`?